# How can I add a simple middleware that will verify JWT and be ensure that is authorized?

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

I have the following middleware that works for authentication with JWT and passport.js. The thing is that I also need somehow verify for all controllers if the user is admin or not. I am using this passport.js middleware for authentication:

```
if (typeof app == "function") {
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
   
    done(null, JSON.stringify(user));
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
   
    done(null, JSON.parse(user));
  });

  var opts = {};
  opts.jwtFromRequest = passportJwtExctract.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
  opts.secretOrKey = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
  passport.use(
    new passportJwtStrategy(opts, async (jwt_payload, done) => {
      var user = await User.findByPk(jwt_payload.id);
      if (user === null) {
        return done(null, false, {
          message: "Sorry, we couldn't find an account.",
        });
      }
      done(null, user);
      await User.update(
        { last_signin_date: "now()" },
        {
          where: {
            id: user.id,
          },
        }
      );
      return;
    })
  );
  passport.use(
    new passportLocalStrategy(
      {
        usernameField: "email",
        passwordField: "password",
      },
      function (username, password, done) {
        process.nextTick(async function () {

          var valid =
            validator.isEmail(username) && validator.isLength(password, 8);
          if (!valid) {
            return done(null, false, {
              message: "Incorrect username or password",
            });
          }

          username = username.toLowerCase();
          let user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: username } });
          user = user.toJSON();
          if (user === undefined) {
            return done(null, false, {
              message: "Sorry, we couldn't find an account with that email.",
            });
          }

          var hashed_password = await bcrypt.hash(password, user.salt);
          if (hashed_password == user.password) {
            delete user.password;
            delete user.salt;
            user.user_mode = process.env.USER_MODE;
            user.token = jwtLib.sign(user, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

            //l('done user', user)
            done(null, user);
            await User.update(
              { last_signin_date: "now()" },
              {
                where: {
                  id: user.id,
                },
              }
            );
            return;
          }
          return done(null, false, {
            message: "Sorry, that password isn't right.",
          });
        });
      }
    )
  );
}
```

How can I verify JWT correctly for all related requests and be sure that the user is admin? Something like the bellow option.

```
Common.ensureAuthenticated("Administrator"),
```

Answer (score 0):

you can investigate about Outh2 authentication where in JWT token you can claim number of parameter according to need and at time of verification you can validate it and extract and use it everywhere you want !

For admin and different different role you can define "actor" as key and its role in respect to priority as value and create a check actor flag at run time !

Comment: you should refer masards/bootstap for jwt Token on github

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your application starts from `index.js` In `index.js`, you can use a middleware before initiating your routes.

For example:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const router = require('./src/router'); // Your router file (router.js)
app.use(AuthMiddleware); // This is how you use your middleware
app.use('/', router);
```